# Replace() in HTML in code behind (VB.NET)

Tags: html, vb.net

```
strbody = strbody & "<font face=""Verdana"" size=""1"">&nbsp;<strong>" + Replace(name, "/", "-") + "</strong></font>"
```

When run the system to send out the email, there is no error in debug but the table interface will haywire because of this Replace(). 
I've tried as below but still not correct. Please help. Tq

Edit:
`Replace(name, "/", "-")` is correct syntax to use in code behind, but now I need to put it in html format in code behind for sending email. So I think I miss out some char to add. Like `<font face=""Verdana""` , I need to put double "

```
'strbody = strbody & "<font face=""Verdana"" size=""1"">&nbsp;<strong>" + Replace(name, "" / "", "" - "") + "</strong></font>"
```

Comment: can you share more details about question

Comment: @Learning pls see the edited question. tq

Comment: I think the problem is elsewhere. That code seems fine. Try `Debug.Print(strbody)`